# Is it possible to make a scrollbar?

Tags: python, interface, add-on

How to make a scrollbar using python ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure what exactly it is you want, so i will just make a guess.

Go into your object properties -> viewport display and enable "Name".
This will show the objects name in the viewport.

[image]

Comment: The user is asking about the tabs in the 3D view sidebar which get clipped when there are too many

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos♦ +++

Comment: I remember this being mentioned on the blender today stream